# LaTeX bibliography: achemso.bst

Tags: article, chemistry, achemso, bst

Where can I find the latest achemso.bst file? At CTAN I cannot find the .bst file, only other files.
Do I need to generate it myself using one of those files?

**EDIT:**

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt]{article}   % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry}       % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper}          % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or...
\usepackage{graphicx}       % support the \includegraphics command and options
% \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}     % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{booktabs}       % for much better looking tables
\usepackage{array}          % for better arrays (eg matrices) in maths
\usepackage{paralist}       % very flexible & customisable lists (eg. enumerate/itemize, etc.)
\usepackage{verbatim}       % adds environment for commenting out blocks of text & for better verbatim
\usepackage{subfig}             % make it possible to include more than one captioned figure/table in a single float

%%% SECTION TITLE APPEARANCE
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape}

%%% Bibliography
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers,super]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
%%%
%\usepackage[style = chem-acs]{biblatex}
%\bibliography{TestBibliography}

\usepackage{subfiles}                   % Best loaded last in the preamble
%%% END Article customizations

%%% The "real" document content comes below...
\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
%\date{} % Activate to display a given date or no date (if empty), otherwise the current date is printed 

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newpage

\section{Introduction}
\subfile{Sections/Introduction}

\section{First section}
Your text goes here.\cite{R1,R2,R3,R4}

\section{Second section}
More text.

%\section{References}
\bibliography{TestBibliography}
%\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

If I use this in the .bib file:

```
% !TeX root = ../TestBibliography.tex

@article{R1,
   author = {G. A. Hembury},
   title = {Chirality-Sensing Supramolecular Systems},
   journaltitle = {Chemical Reviews},
   year = {2008},
   volume = {108},
   pages = {1},
}
```

However, when I add et al. to the .bib file, it even becomes worse:

[image]

```
% !TeX root = ../TestBibliography.tex

@article{R1,
   author = {G. A. Hembury et al.},
   title = {Chirality-Sensing Supramolecular Systems},
   journaltitle = {Chemical Reviews},
   year = {2008},
   volume = {108},
   pages = {1},
}
```

I want it as (so basically it should take the authors as how I write it in the .bib file):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKmWS.png) G. A. Hembury et al., Chirality-Sensing Supramolecular Systems. **2008**, *108*, 1.

Comment: Did you try to see whether `biblatex-chem`, which has a `chem-acs` style corresponds to what you want?

Comment: achemso.bst is in the dtx. You can unpack it by compiling the achemso.ins with latex https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso. But it is also in the tex systems, so with an up-to-date miktex or texlive you should be able to install it with their package managers.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, it works but it does not give the name of the authors as I wrote in the .bib file, e.g. B. Olbama, but instead it gives it as: B. O. 
I want to edit it such that everything is in the acs style except the name, which should be as given above.

Comment: Could you post a short, yet complete, example code illustrating your problem?

Comment: @Bernard I edited the post!

Comment: Do you have the names of the other authors?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, but I basically use EndNote to generate the .bib file, so the naming I do beforehand.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you!!

Comment: Try `author = {G. A. Hembury and others},`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, I see. "and others" is being replaced by et al. I didn't know, thank you again! Is there also a way to swap the first name and last name? When I change ```names.str current.name.int "{vv~}{ll,}{~f.}{,~jj}" format.name$``` to ```names.str current.name.int "{f.~}{vv~}{ll,}{,~jj}" format.name$``` I get twice a comma so ,, et al, and if I remove the comma in {ll,}, the et al. gets replaced by ; others